# ORDER BY when using value gotten from sql function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this SQL for creating the procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[spGetProduct](@col_sort varchar(100), @dir_sort varchar(4), @filters nvarchar(max)) as
begin
declare @temp table (
        row_num int,
        product_id int,
        product_name nvarchar(255),
        produnit_name nvarchar(50)
    )

insert into @temp
    EXEC('select * from (select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '+@col_sort+' '+@dir_sort+')) row_num, product_id, product_name, dbo.fnGetUnitName(ing_produnit) produnit_name
     from dbo.Products
     where '+@filters+') as tmp)

select * from @temp
end
```

Info:

`dir_sort` can be `asc` or `desc` and `col_sort` is a string that contains one of the column names.

Filters in this case is irrelevant.

When `col_sort` has the value `product_id` or `product_name` it is working fine, but when I call it with `produnit_name` it throws error.

How can I order the data by that column in this case?

Edit:

The error is:

> Invalid column name 'produnit_name'.

Comment: It throws ***what*** error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in the `OVER()` clause at the same scope, since the alias is defined *after* the `OVER()` clause is evaluated. This is the same reason you can't `GROUP BY alias` or say `WHERE alias = 1` - the alias hasn't been defined yet in those cases, either.

If you can't use a join instead of the function to derive the unit name, then you will have to nest again, e.g.

```
insert into @temp
EXEC('select * from (select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (ORDER BY '+@col_sort+' '+@dir_sort+')) row_num, * FROM 
    (SELECT product_id, product_name, 
      dbo.fnGetUnitName(ing_produnit) produnit_name
      from dbo.Products
      where '+@filters+') AS x) as tmp');
```

Comment: This is working at the moment, but i cant use it as a solution the query takes too much time if col_sort is produnit_name.
Is there another way i can make this faster?

Comment: Performance is a different issue altogether - your question was because of a syntax error and you should keep it that way. If you don't have a supporting index for a certain outcome, then this becomes a much different question (and you should post it separately - in fact it has nothing to do with the code in your question, just reproduce it with a hard-coded query). Perhaps you should create indexes to support all of your scenarios, or maybe not offer scenarios where you know the performance will be slow.

Comment: You are right this is a solution for my original question.Many thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `produnit_name` is a derived column. While you can use a derived column in an ORDER BY clause, you cannot use it with `ROW_NUMBER OVER`.